# Weblogic returning http response starting with 0000

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, weblogic

we have a web-application for which sometimes weblogic returns HTML page starting with 0000 and hence browser is not able to render it properly.

This is working fine when we have deployed the same application in JBoss.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: Do you mean that the HTML page is updated by weblogic to add "0000" at the begining of the document ?
it sounds like an application issue and not a weblogic server issue.

Comment: "0000" is appended to the HTML response. It is an intermittent issue. It shouldn't be application issue as this behaviour is only seen in weblogic and not on jboss(same application)

Comment: What is the version of weblogic server ?

Comment: Do you know if it happens with GET/POST/HEAD requests ?

Comment: weblogic version is 10.36 and it is happening mostly for GET type of requests

Comment: post the curl --verbose

Answer (score 0):

I know that is old ticket, but since there was no solution posted and it happened to me today, I would like to share our fix.

In our case(Spring boot app deployed in Weblogic) the solution was that for every put request we return 204 'Accepted' and not 202 'No content'